# UITableViewCellStyleValue1 detailTextLabel show the wrong way

Tags: iphone, detailtextlabel

when i make a detailTextLabel  i just want to let it right in the label but it always down the textLabel how i change it just like the UITableViewCellStyleValue1 demo ?

Comment: Not clear at all? Can you try to reframe your question to make it understandable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the cell property of your detail text label right alignment like below

```
cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight
```